# Update bar chart and removing labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bar chart, I want to update the data and also the values of the coordinates. So far I was only successful at removing the bars but I can't remove the labels for the x-axis and the y-axis. I used svg.selectAll(".bar").remove(); 
but it only removed the bars and left the x-axis and the y-axis.

How do I remove the labels of the axes ?

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function (error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
            return d.letter;
        }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return d.frequency;
        })]);

        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Frequency");

        svg.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function (d) {
                    return x(d.letter);
                })
                .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                .attr("y", function (d) {
                    return y(d.frequency);
                })
                .attr("height", function (d) {
                    return height - y(d.frequency);
                });
    });
function updateData(input) {


        svg.selectAll(".bar").remove();}
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to be

`svg.select all(".bar").data(data).exit().remove();`

EDIT:

This is how your update function should be:

```
function updateData() {

    d3.tsv("data2.tsv", function(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

        var barEnter = svg.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(data)
                .enter().
                .append("rect");

        var barUpdate = svg.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(data)
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
                .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });

        var barExit = svg.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(data)
                .exit()
                .remove();

        d3.transition(svg).select(".x.axis")
            .transition()
            .duration(100)
            .call(xAxis)

        d3.transition(svg).select(".y.axis")
            .transition()
            .duration(100)
            .call(yAxis)

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but it didn't work, the labels are still there, even a few bars from the old data remained. the full code is here if you want to try yourself. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304

Comment: Is `input` your new data? If yes, just write `.data(input`. `Selection().exit()` binds the new data to the selection, and selects all the elements without the new data.

Comment: But if you want to remove all the bars and the respective axis labels, just make your `data` an empty array.

Comment: Just a silly question: are you calling the axes again? Can you share your *entire* code for checking this?

Comment: okay, I tried but maybe it's my fault. Anyway my goals is simple. I have a file called data2.tsv I want the update function to load the data from this file, how should the update function be like ?

Comment: yes, I want to name the axes again.  I'll share the code in a minute, but I think now you understand the whole picture.

Comment: I'll check your code. Meanwhile, this is a tutorial regarding updating bar charts: http://www.davesquared.net/2014/09/d3-update-a-bar-chart.html

Comment: And this one shows how to deal with two CSVs (or TSVs): http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8

Comment: Thanks Gerardo, My problem is with the x-axis when I update the chart. 
I checked the tutorial before. I guess I need a line similar to this 
chart.select(".x.axis").remove();

except that when i add it to my code, chart isn't defined.